# Google Maps API - Places Autocomplete Usage limits

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API places autocomplete. I initially load the script using `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places` (Note no API key) and invoke the plugin using `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input)`.

I've analysed a whole load of documentation trying to find out what the licensing is to no avail and wanted to see if anyone knows. The autocomplete is not used in conjunction with any map, necessary to note as all the documentation I've found thus far makes reference to gMaps and other services when talking about an autocomplete.

If there is a request limit, what counts as a request? Searching for 'London' is six characters, so is that six requests?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage ?

Comment: just make lab test: type something then look at the dev console to see usage

Comment: Also, note that when you're using the Places library via the Maps API, requests are governed by this > https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Comment: @BenM `Note: These limits do not apply to the Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API, which is covered by the Google Maps JavaScript API limits`, but the JS API limits make reference to a load of other stuff, which is why I ask because I'm completely confused

Comment: @michael actually, using the Places library without displaying results on a map *isn't* forbidden. You're probably thinking of the Geolocation API or similar. Google even explains how to accredit use without a map, for example: **If your application displays Google Places API data on a page or view that does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by Google" logo with that data.** (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I contacted Google Sales and they said

> Using the places autocomplete JS API **WITHOUT** any map loads is **FREE**

Correct as of 5th October 2015